# How to get file path of selected file?

Tags: c#

```
var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "(*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.JPG;*.GIF";
dlg.ShowDialog();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dlg.FileName)) return;
var fs = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var data = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close()
```

I browse the pic like this but now i need the path also.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you [looked at the documentation on MSDN?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) - there are two properties `FileName` and `FileNames` ....

Comment: hmm.. he said he need the *path* ... not filename. Evidently, he is already using dlg.FileName....

Comment: Only Jake understand my question i know File Name give the complete path with file name but i want only path of file. First you understand then decrease the point not without thinking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Path.GetDirectoryName(dlg.Filename)`